# split a string by a character without strtok in c

Tags: c

I need to write code that reads a string of characters such as `jasf@fjaf@afsj` to a single dimension string and then ask for a separation character (eg: `@`) so it will get an output in two dimensions and for every line, it will be the words between the separation character like:

```
jasf
fjaf
afsj
```

I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

void main {
    int s, k, b;
    printf("please enter a long string\n");

    gets(longstring);
    s = strlen(longstring);
    printf("please choose seperationg charcter\n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    if ((ch < 'A') || ((ch > 'Z') && (ch < 'a')) || (ch > 'z')) {
        for (k = 0; k < s; k++) {
            for (b = 0; longstring[k] == ch; ++b) {
                strcpy(mat[b], longstring);
            }
        }
        puts(mat[b]);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: without pointers

Comment: Why "without pointers?"  Is this one of those pointlessly-restrictive homework assignments that asks you to find "creative" ways of, in effect, driving nails without a hammer?  Or is there some other reason?  (I ask because this is a particularly pointless restriction.  C is built around pointers.  This problem cries out to be solved using pointers.  This problem is straightforwardly solved using pointers.  Trying to solve it without pointers will be difficult, confusing, and likely impossible.)

Comment: Exactly, one of the homework assignments that asks for creative ways

Answer (score 0):

since your code is not complete , let me add what is missing to achieve the task :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
    char** result    = 0;
    size_t count     = 0;
    char* tmp        = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
     knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char longstring[1024];
    char** tokens;
    char ch;

    unsigned long s;

    printf("please enter a long string\n");
    gets(longstring);
    s = strlen(longstring);
    printf("please choose seperationg charcter\n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    if ((ch<'A') || ((ch>'Z') && (ch<'a')) || (ch>'z'))
    {
        tokens = str_split(longstring, ch);

        if (tokens)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++)
            {
                printf("%s\n", *(tokens + i));
                free(*(tokens + i));
            }
            printf("\n");
            free(tokens);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete: the function definition for `main` lacks its argument list, which is not optional in C, `longstring` is not defined, etc.

Futhermore, your method is too complicated: you do not need to test for letters if the goal is just to output one line for each part of the string between separators.

Here is a simple solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char longstring[256];
    int i, len;
    char sep;

    printf("please enter a long string\n");
    if (fgets(longstring, sizeof longstring, stdin)) {
        len = strlen(longstring);
        printf("please choose a separationg character: ");
        if (scanf("%c", &sep) != 1)
            return 1;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (longstring[i] == sep)
                putchar('\n');
            else
                putchar(longstring[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```